# How to make radius of one edge bigger than of a rest

Tags: modeling

I have a round cube 100x150x100mm with radius 2mm (standard mesh shape). I want to make one edge more rounded than the rest - with radius 10mm. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select edge you want to bevel 10 mm and *Assign* to *Vertex Group*
- Add *Bevel* modifier > Amounth 0.010 > Limit > **Vertex Group**
- Add *Bevel* modifier > Amounth 0.002 > Limit > **Angle**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason Blender crashes when I try to open your .blend file. Could you, please, upload a short screencast on how you achieve this?

Comment: which version of Blender did you use here?

Comment: Sorry for silent, I use blender 2.92 (experimental). BTW I quickly checked Ramos's answer and that is better way of doing this :)